# Callback function not get called in jasmine test code

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I'm using jasmine 2.0 for testing and I'm spying on the jquery ajax and returning a promise.
In the done() function method displayContent() doesn't get called but the console message above it gets shown up. Where am I going wrong ?

test.js

```
it(..., function() {
   var data = {"name" : "John Doe"};
   spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (req) {
     var d = $.Deferred();
     d.resolve(data);   
     return d.promise();
   });

   app.doSomething();
   expect(app.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

app.js

```
app.getData = function() {
  var jsonData = app.loadEmpData();   //gets replaced by spy and returns resolve(data);
  jsonData.done(function(data) {
      console.log("shows up in the console");
      app.displayContent(data);  // doesn't get called 
  });
  jsonData.fail(function(){
      console.log("error loading data");
  });
}

app.loadEmpData = function() {
   return $.getJSON("/employee.json");
}

app.displayContent = function() {
   console.log("some content");
}

app.doSomething = function() {
  app.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spy on the `displayContent()` and check if it is called or not.
I modified your test and `displayContent()` was called.
Replace with this code and check.

```
it("some test", function() {
    var data = {"name" : "John Doe"};
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (req) {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve(data);   
        return d.promise();
    });
    spyOn(app, 'displayContent').and.callThrough();
    app.getData();
    expect(app.displayContent).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

In Jasmine 2.0 `and.callThrough();` will delegate to the actual implementation of `displayContent()`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. How would one go about to test a failed ajax call? ".fail(function() { code to be tested });

Answer (score 2):

Two possible options pop up in my head:

1) In some scenarios you should call $scope.apply() in your test code to ensure the promise's then function is executed.

2) You could use the done() function, like this:

```
it('', function(done){
  $promise.then(function(){
    expect(...);
    done();
  })
});
```